# UIKit Dynamics/Blocks - Remove UIPushBehavior on Complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, block, microsoft-dynamics

I applied a UIPushBehavior to an object. It moves. How can I trigger a method on completion of this movement? (e.g. When it's movement velocity drops to below a certain threshold).

As far as I see there is no "StateEnded" callback I could use to trigger such a method. There is however a action block that is called on each step

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
...
    _parentViewController.pushBehavior.action =  ^{
       //Called on each animation/dynamics step

    };
...
}
```

But I cannot get current values inside that block. Any ideas how to trigger an action based on current values inside the block? ... or a different way to do make the object do something based on it's movement/velocity state?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using the UIDynamicAnimator "running" property.